# How to turn off a circuit with a ON/OFF switch

Tags: switches

I`m designing a circuit and I want to turn it on and off. I have two linear regulator and a step-up switch regulator in it. If I use a switch that connects the input pin of the regulator to the battery positive pole or open it, do I have a ON/OFF button or can I have malfunction doing so?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a schematic, would help a lot. ... Actually on second thought, I think I get it. Yes you can have a switch there. No problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEIaop.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That'll work just fine. Regardless of the regulator type and how many are connected to the battery.

Answer (score 0):

If your switch is momentary then there are some additional complexities.  Linear has some nice ICs if you want to avoid any headaches with this and make it a pretty "brain dead" design.

http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/2955f.pdf

They have nice schematics in there that show you exactly how to do what you're trying to do.  If it's not a momentary switch then of course the answer that Samuel provided above is great.